# Ant Design Upload: preview one image only?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to simply only allow upload of one image, so if a user clicks upload again, there should only be **ONE image previewed**... not 2.

I already know how to deal with only uploading 1 image, but can't figure out how to only preview one image, using Ant Upload's image preview.

Code example:

```
import { Upload, Button } from 'antd';
import { UploadOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const fileList = [
  {
    uid: '-1',
    name: 'xxx.png',
    status: 'done',
    url: 'https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/jkjgkEfvpUPVyRjUImniVslZfWPnJuuZ.png',
    thumbUrl: 'https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/jkjgkEfvpUPVyRjUImniVslZfWPnJuuZ.png',
  }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <>
    <Upload
      action="https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76"
      listType="picture"
      defaultFileList={[...fileList]}
    >
      <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Upload</Button>
    </Upload>
    <br />
    <br />
    <Upload
      listType="picture"
      defaultFileList={[...fileList]}
    >
      <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Upload</Button>
    </Upload>
  </>,
  mountNode,
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `Upload` component to be a **controlled** component by specifying the `fileList` prop.

```
const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([...])

<Upload fileList={fileList}>
    <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Upload</Button>
</Upload>
```

If you try the above code, you will notice that when you upload something, nothing happens. To change it, you need to modify the state on Upload `onChange` callback. See this [link](https://ant.design/components/upload/#onChange) for more info about the Upload `onChange` prop. To preview only one image, just set the state to your last upload only.

```
const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([...])

const handleChange = (info) => {
    let fileList = [...info.fileList];

    // 1. Limit the number of uploaded files
    // Only to show the last recent uploaded files, and old ones will be replaced by the new
    fileList = fileList.slice(-1);
    setFileList(fileList);
};

<Upload fileList={fileList} onChange={handleChange}>
    <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Upload</Button>
</Upload>
```

See complete code here:

[image: Edit]

this can also help. [Complete control over file list](https://ant.design/components/upload/#components-upload-demo-fileList)